# Controls não Aparecem no Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms

Após atualização para o Windows 10, sumiram os componentes nos meus formulários, aparece apenas o cursor no campo. Já troquei cores do fundo, das fontes, porem, não funcionou.

VisualStudio 2013, Net Framework 4.5. Print Windows 7 e Print Windows 10

Formulários:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara Só por Curiosidade na maquina a onde esta instalado não tem nenhum plugin do banco do brasil rodando ?

Comment: Tem o da caixa e do BB

Comment: Este mesmo problema ocorreu aqui na empresa, não era em nenhuma versão específica do sistema, e eram em computadores aleatórios de clientes aleatórios. Não existia nenhum tipo de padrão que pudemos identificar que ocasionava o problema, tentamos atualizar a versão do .net framework do cliente e nada. Depois de algumas semanas, os computadores que apresentavam o problema, simplesmente pararam de apresentar.E até hoje a causa e a solução do problema permanecem como mistério.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao atualizar do Windows 7 para o Windows 10 o driver de vídeo não fornecia mais compatibilidade, deixando assim os formulários de vários sistemas como as fotos em anexo a pergunta.
Atualizando o driver de vídeo para o compatível com o Windows 10 fornecido pelo fabricante da placa o erro foi resolvido!

Comment: Foi alterado, essa foi a solução do meu problema, não tem mais detalhes. Só posso marcar como resposta dentro de dois dias.